# Is it valid to model a discrete numerical test score as a continuous response variable for regression analysis?

Tags: regression, logistic, ordered-logit

I have a set of scores from a patient reported outcome scale.  The variables are ordinal.  There are 5000 scores collected between 0 to 2 years after enrollment in a study.  The object of this analysis is to predict the the test score at two years based on the initial score and some clinical variables.

Comment: Can you say more about the reported outcome scale? e.g. how many different values are there?

Answer (score 0):

Might have answered my question, but I'll keep my question and my answer here for others to critique and/or use.

Looks like the solution is to use an ordered logit model:

http://data.princeton.edu/wws509/stata/c6s5.html

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_logit